# python How do i save a variable from a loop and get it back later

Tags: python

So I want to save a variable from my loop but when it restarts it changes the variable

```
print('Dice script')
for i in range(3):
  print('Rolling')
  time.sleep(1)
  droll = (randint(1, 6))
  sdroll = str(droll)
  print('Dice rolled '+ sdroll)
  time.sleep(3)
add = (Here I want to add up the variables that i got from the three loops)
print(add)
```

so that I get the variable `droll` all three times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list to save `sdroll` values on each iteration, this way:

```
sdroll_list= []
print('Dice script')
for i in range(3):
    print('Rolling')
    time.sleep(1)
    droll = (randint(1, 6))
    sdroll = str(droll)
    sdroll_list.append(sdroll)
    print('Dice rolled '+ sdroll)
    time.sleep(3)
add_string = ' '.join(sdroll_list)) #Concatenate the strings in sdroll_list
add_values = sum(map(int, sdroll_list)) #Sum values converted from sdroll_list
print(add)
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to `sum` the values of `droll` of each iteration, do it as below:

```
print('Dice script')
sum_droll = 0
for i in range(3):
    print('Rolling')
    time.sleep(1)
    droll = (randint(1, 6))
    sum_droll += droll #sum droll values
    sdroll = str(droll)
    print('Dice rolled '+ sdroll)
    time.sleep(3)
print(sum_droll)
```

Comment: @Joshuas_cool ... Is your purpose is to find total sum of `droll` ?

Comment: Yes and Thank you I was confused I thought that once the loop changes the variable you could not get it back. Thx

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the sum and you don't need to know what the individual outcomes were, you could sum them in the loop itself.

```
sdroll_sum = 0
print('Dice script')
for i in range(3):
    print('Rolling')
    time.sleep(1)
    droll = (randint(1, 6))
    sdroll_sum += droll
    print('Dice rolled '+ str(droll))
    time.sleep(3)
print(sdroll_sum)
```